# Why debugger stops on `use` statement?

Tags: perl, debugging

When we enclose this code into braces:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

{
    use warnings 'void';
    1;
}
```

The debugger stops on `use warnings 'void'` statement:

```
main::(/home/kes/tmp/t3.pl:4):      use warnings 'void';
  DB<1> l 1-20
1   #!/usr/bin/env perl
2   
3   {
4==>    use warnings 'void';
5:      1;
6   }
7
```

But if we do not:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl


use warnings 'void';
1;
```

The debugger **does not** stop on `use warnings 'void'` statement:

```
main::(/home/kes/tmp/t3.pl:5):      1;
  DB<1> l 1-20
1   #!/usr/bin/env perl
2   
3   
4:      use warnings 'void';
5==>    1;
6   
7
```

But, as we can see, `line 4` still marked as breakable.

What are differences in these examples
and why debugger does not stop on `line 4`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `use` statement is never added to the compiled program because it is executed at compile-time.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'use warnings qw( void ); f()'
1  <0> enter
2  <;> nextstate(main 2 -e:1) v:{
3  <0> pushmark s
4  <#> gv[*f] s/EARLYCV
5  <1> entersub[t2] vKS/TARG
6  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

As such, the debugger is never actually stopping on the `use` statement. Let's look at the compiled form of both programs:

```
$ perl -MO=Concise
{
   use warnings qw( void );
   1;
}
^D
6  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 1 -:2) v:{ ->3
5     <2> leaveloop vK/2 ->6
3        <{> enterloop(next->5 last->5 redo->4) v ->4
-        <@> lineseq vKP ->5
4           <;> nextstate(main 3 -:3) v:{ ->5
-           <0> ex-const v ->-
- syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Concise
use warnings qw( void );
1;
^D
3  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 2 -:2) v:{ ->3
-     <0> ex-const v ->3
- syntax OK
```

`nextstate` ops set the line number for run-time warnings. (For example, `-:2` means line 2 of the code read from STDIN.) The debugger is also using these to know where to break and to find the line in the source file of the current statement.

The second snippet has only one run-time statement, so it has a single `nextstate` op at which the debugger stop.

The first snippet, however, has two statements. A bare loop (`{ ... }`), and a constant. The bare loop creates a `nextstate` op with the line of the first non-whitespace character that follows the `{`, which happens to be the `use warnings;`. I'm not sure why it does this.

Comment: Seems like a hot hack at perl internals

Comment: I don't understand. What's a "hot hack"?

Comment: I suppose, If bare loop did not create `nextstate` op the `nextstate` op of next statement will be used and debugger will not stop on 'use' statement.

Comment: Exactly, as it should. The debugger effectivement stopped on a comment,  not code